# Changing styles on JavaFX on the code and event handler

Tags: css, javafx, scenebuilder

I have two questions that left me in doubt.

**1Q:** Suppose I have a button, and via SceneBuilder I set the Style of a button to *"-fx-border-color: #FFFFFF"* and it was in the fxml file. Suppose I also added other styles to it too.

I created an event when the mouse enters the button. If I want to create an effect, for example the color of the border changes when the mouse enters and exits, I would have to do it by putting ***setStyle*** in the event and in the parameter I put all the styles that I already have and change only what I want? e.g: in the *Button* i have the styles *a, b, c, -fx-border-color: #FFFFFF, d, e*. For do that effect i would have to do: Button.setStyle("a,b,c,-fx-border-color: #AAAAAA, d, e") or there is a better way to do it?

**2Q:** In a similar case, if I want to make the button go up a little on the Y axis when hovering, would I have to create a different event for each button and associate them via SceneBuilder? e.g:

```
@FXML
void onMouseEnterEvent(MouseEvent event) {
    button_NewProject.setLayoutY(button_NewProject.getLayoutY()-8);
}
```

I created the code above an then realize that i can't actually handle this same event for all buttons, cause if i do it, all the buttons would go up when hovering a single button. I'm wrong? what do i need to do here?

Comment: Try `event.getSource`.

Comment: java naming conventions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo that can hopefully help. If you have one button handler that handles more than one button, you need to make use of `event.getSource`. `event.getSource` will return the button that is receiving the action.

**handleBtnOnAction Demo's this.**

```
@FXML
    public void handleBtnOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Button tempButton = ((Button)event.getSource());
        System.out.println("You pressed button " + tempButton.getText() + "  - ID: " + tempButton.getId());
    }
```

**Full Code**

**Main**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author sedrick (sedj601)
 */
public class JavaFXApplication6 extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

**Controller**

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

/**
 *
 * @author sedrick (sedj601)
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    @FXML GridPane gpMain;
    
    int turn = 0;
    List<String> styles = new ArrayList();
    
    @FXML
    public void handleBtnOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Button tempButton = ((Button)event.getSource());
        System.out.println("You pressed button " + tempButton.getText() + "  - ID: " + tempButton.getId());
    }
    
    @FXML
    public void handleStartDemoBtnOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Button tempStartDemoButton = (Button)event.getSource();
        tempStartDemoButton.setText("Change Buttons' ID");
       
        Collections.shuffle(styles);//Changes the styles location in the list. 
        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
        gpMain.getChildren().forEach((node) -> {//get gridpane buttons
            System.out.println(((Button)node).getText() + ": " + styles.get(counter.get()));
            node.setId(styles.get(counter.getAndIncrement()));//Set the buttons CSS ID.
        });
    }
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        styles.add("green");
        styles.add("round-red");
        styles.add("bevel-grey");
        styles.add("glass-grey");
        styles.add("shiny-orange");
        styles.add("dark-blue");
        styles.add("record-sales");
        styles.add("rich-blue");
        styles.add("big-yellow");
        styles.add("iphone");
        styles.add("ipad-dark-grey");
        styles.add("ipad-grey");
        styles.add("lion-default");
        styles.add("lion");
        styles.add("windows7-default");
        styles.add("windows7");
        styles.add("green");   
    }    
    
}
```

**FXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" spacing="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication6.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <GridPane fx:id="gpMain" hgap="5.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" stylesheets="@main.css" vgap="5.0">
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="200.0" minWidth="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="200.0" minWidth="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="200.0" minWidth="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="200.0" minHeight="200.0" prefHeight="200.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="200.0" minHeight="200.0" prefHeight="200.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="200.0" minHeight="200.0" prefHeight="200.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
         </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleBtnOnAction" text="1" />
            <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleBtnOnAction" text="2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
            <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleBtnOnAction" text="3" GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
            <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleBtnOnAction" text="4" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleBtnOnAction" text="5" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleBtnOnAction" text="6" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleBtnOnAction" text="7" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleBtnOnAction" text="8" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleBtnOnAction" text="9" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
      <Button maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleStartDemoBtnOnAction" prefHeight="100.0" text="Start Demo" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

**CSS**

```
/*
    Code from http://fxexperience.com/2011/12/styling-fx-buttons-with-css/
*/

#green {
    -fx-background-color:
        linear-gradient(#f0ff35, #a9ff00),
        radial-gradient(center 50% -40%, radius 200%, #b8ee36 45%, #80c800 50%);
    -fx-background-radius: 6, 5;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.4) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );
    -fx-text-fill: #395306;
}
#round-red {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#ff5400, #be1d00);
    -fx-background-radius: 30;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
#bevel-grey {
    -fx-background-color: 
        linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #d6d6d6),
        linear-gradient(#fcfcfc 0%, #d9d9d9 20%, #d6d6d6 100%),
        linear-gradient(#dddddd 0%, #f6f6f6 50%);
    -fx-background-radius: 8,7,6;
    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,2;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );
}
#glass-grey {
    -fx-background-color: 
        #c3c4c4,
        linear-gradient(#d6d6d6 50%, white 100%),
        radial-gradient(center 50% -40%, radius 200%, #e6e6e6 45%, rgba(230,230,230,0) 50%);
    -fx-background-radius: 30;
    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,1;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 3, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );
}
#shiny-orange {
    -fx-background-color: 
        linear-gradient(#ffd65b, #e68400),
        linear-gradient(#ffef84, #f2ba44),
        linear-gradient(#ffea6a, #efaa22),
        linear-gradient(#ffe657 0%, #f8c202 50%, #eea10b 100%),
        linear-gradient(from 0% 0% to 15% 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9), rgba(255,255,255,0));
    -fx-background-radius: 30;
    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,2,3,0;
    -fx-text-fill: #654b00;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-font-size: 14px;
    -fx-padding: 10 20 10 20;
}
#dark-blue {
    -fx-background-color: 
        #090a0c,
        linear-gradient(#38424b 0%, #1f2429 20%, #191d22 100%),
        linear-gradient(#20262b, #191d22),
        radial-gradient(center 50% 0%, radius 100%, rgba(114,131,148,0.9), rgba(255,255,255,0));
    -fx-background-radius: 5,4,3,5;
    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,2,0;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );
    -fx-font-family: "Arial";
    -fx-text-fill: linear-gradient(white, #d0d0d0);
    -fx-font-size: 12px;
    -fx-padding: 10 20 10 20;
}
#dark-blue Text {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.9) , 1, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );
}
#record-sales {
    -fx-padding: 8 15 15 15;
    -fx-background-insets: 0,0 0 5 0, 0 0 6 0, 0 0 7 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 8;
    -fx-background-color: 
        linear-gradient(from 0% 93% to 0% 100%, #a34313 0%, #903b12 100%),
        #9d4024,
        #d86e3a,
        radial-gradient(center 50% 50%, radius 100%, #d86e3a, #c54e2c);
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( gaussian , rgba(0,0,0,0.75) , 4,0,0,1 );
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-font-size: 1.1em;
}
#record-sales:hover {
    -fx-background-color: 
        linear-gradient(from 0% 93% to 0% 100%, #a34313 0%, #903b12 100%),
        #9d4024,
        #d86e3a,
        radial-gradient(center 50% 50%, radius 100%, #ea7f4b, #c54e2c);
}
#record-sales:pressed {
    -fx-padding: 10 15 13 15;
    -fx-background-insets: 2 0 0 0,2 0 3 0, 2 0 4 0, 2 0 5 0;
}
#record-sales Text {
    -fx-fill: white;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( gaussian , #a30000 , 0,0,0,2 );
}
#rich-blue {
    -fx-background-color: 
        #000000,
        linear-gradient(#7ebcea, #2f4b8f),
        linear-gradient(#426ab7, #263e75),
        linear-gradient(#395cab, #223768);
    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,2,3;
    -fx-background-radius: 3,2,2,2;
    -fx-padding: 12 30 12 30;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-font-size: 12px;
}
#rich-blue Text {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.8) , 0, 0.0 , 0 , 1);
}
#big-yellow {
    -fx-background-color: 
        #ecebe9,
        rgba(0,0,0,0.05),
        linear-gradient(#dcca8a, #c7a740),
        linear-gradient(#f9f2d6 0%, #f4e5bc 20%, #e6c75d 80%, #e2c045 100%),
        linear-gradient(#f6ebbe, #e6c34d);
    -fx-background-insets: 0,9 9 8 9,9,10,11;
    -fx-background-radius: 50;
    -fx-padding: 15 30 15 30;
    -fx-font-family: "Helvetica";
    -fx-font-size: 18px;
    -fx-text-fill: #311c09;
    -fx-effect: innershadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.1) , 2, 0.0 , 0 , 1);
}
#big-yellow Text {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , rgba(255,255,255,0.5) , 0, 0.0 , 0 , 1);
}
#iphone-toolbar {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#98a8bd 0%, #8195af 25%, #6d86a4 100%);
}
#iphone {
    -fx-background-color: 
        #a6b5c9,
        linear-gradient(#303842 0%, #3e5577 20%, #375074 100%),
        linear-gradient(#768aa5 0%, #849cbb 5%, #5877a2 50%, #486a9a 51%, #4a6c9b 100%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0,0,1;
    -fx-background-radius: 5,5,4;
    -fx-padding: 7 30 7 30;
    -fx-text-fill: #242d35;
    -fx-font-family: "Helvetica";
    -fx-font-size: 12px;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
#iphone Text {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.8) , 0, 0.0 , 0 , -1 );
}
#ipad-dark-grey {
    -fx-background-color: 
        linear-gradient(#686868 0%, #232723 25%, #373837 75%, #757575 100%),
        linear-gradient(#020b02, #3a3a3a),
        linear-gradient(#9d9e9d 0%, #6b6a6b 20%, #343534 80%, #242424 100%),
        linear-gradient(#8a8a8a 0%, #6b6a6b 20%, #343534 80%, #262626 100%),
        linear-gradient(#777777 0%, #606060 50%, #505250 51%, #2a2b2a 100%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,4,5,6;
    -fx-background-radius: 9,8,5,4,3;
    -fx-padding: 15 30 15 30;
    -fx-font-family: "Helvetica";
    -fx-font-size: 18px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(255,255,255,0.2) , 1, 0.0 , 0 , 1);
}
#ipad-dark-grey Text {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , black , 0, 0.0 , 0 , -1 );
}
#ipad-grey {
    -fx-background-color: 
        linear-gradient(#686868 0%, #232723 25%, #373837 75%, #757575 100%),
        linear-gradient(#020b02, #3a3a3a),
        linear-gradient(#b9b9b9 0%, #c2c2c2 20%, #afafaf 80%, #c8c8c8 100%),
        linear-gradient(#f5f5f5 0%, #dbdbdb 50%, #cacaca 51%, #d7d7d7 100%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,4,5;
    -fx-background-radius: 9,8,5,4;
    -fx-padding: 15 30 15 30;
    -fx-font-family: "Helvetica";
    -fx-font-size: 18px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-text-fill: #333333;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(255,255,255,0.2) , 1, 0.0 , 0 , 1);
}
#ipad-grey Text {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , white , 0, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );
}
#lion-default {
    -fx-background-color: 
        rgba(0,0,0,0.08),
        linear-gradient(#5a61af, #51536d),
        linear-gradient(#e4fbff 0%,#cee6fb 10%, #a5d3fb 50%, #88c6fb 51%, #d5faff 100%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0,0,1;
    -fx-background-radius: 5,5,4;
    -fx-padding: 3 30 3 30;
    -fx-text-fill: #242d35;
    -fx-font-size: 14px;
}
#lion {
    -fx-background-color: 
        rgba(0,0,0,0.08),
        linear-gradient(#9a9a9a, #909090),
        linear-gradient(white 0%, #f3f3f3 50%, #ececec 51%, #f2f2f2 100%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0,0,1;
    -fx-background-radius: 5,5,4;
    -fx-padding: 3 30 3 30;
    -fx-text-fill: #242d35;
    -fx-font-size: 14px;
}
#windows7-default {
    -fx-background-color: 
        #3c7fb1,
        linear-gradient(#fafdfe, #e8f5fc),
        linear-gradient(#eaf6fd 0%, #d9f0fc 49%, #bee6fd 50%, #a7d9f5 100%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,2;
    -fx-background-radius: 3,2,1;
    -fx-padding: 3 30 3 30;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-font-size: 14px;
}
#windows7 {
    -fx-background-color: 
        #707070,
        linear-gradient(#fcfcfc, #f3f3f3),
        linear-gradient(#f2f2f2 0%, #ebebeb 49%, #dddddd 50%, #cfcfcf 100%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,2;
    -fx-background-radius: 3,2,1;
    -fx-padding: 3 30 3 30;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-font-size: 14px;
}
```

[image]

CSS is from http://fxexperience.com/2011/12/styling-fx-buttons-with-css/!

Comment: Incredible, it helped a lot, you have no idea. Thank you very much <3